# Inverse MOD a tree up to it's divisors from a prime number

Tags: python, math, primes, prime-factoring

Is there any way to inverse mod a tree to get the results below without brute force?

```
# In [445]: findtreeup(31776288,1823)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# Out[445]: [1823, 2395, 4141, 12613, 1270547, 4357963, 5483665, 26292623]
```

So 31776288%26292623 = 5483665
and 31776288%4357963 = 1270547
and so forth,

but i want to start from the prime number 1823, and reverse walk up the tree. Is that possible?

My current program uses a brute force method:

```
def findtreeup(hm, start):
   vv = []
   vv.append(start)
   for x in range(start, hm):
      if hm%x == start:
         start = x
         vv.append(start)
   return vv
```

Any help as to why or why not would be helpful. Thanks!

A shortcut down the tree would be very helpful as well, is there a way to jump from 26292623 down to 1823, skipping the in between?

Comment: Which part of this makes a tree? Or is it just in the sense that a linked list is a tree?

Comment: It's a tree that walks down to a prime number, 1823 from this case when % mod'ing from 31776288 and starting from 26292623.   What i want to do is the reverse without brute force. Start from 1823, and use a math formula to get me 2395. Then from 2395 run the same math formula to get me 4141. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I don’t understand. Could you show the tree, please?

Comment: It's more like a 'path'. A tree has branches.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your question:

> Given a number eg. `31776288` and a prime eg. `1823` find the finite series S such that:
>
> S_1 = `1823`
>
> S_n-1 = `31776288` % S_n

Which implies:

> S_1 = `31776288` % S_2
>
> `1823` = `31776288` % S_2

By considering `1823` modulo some numbers we are able to make inferences about S_2:

> `2k + 1` = `2m` % S_2

(For some integers, k and m)

By considering this case, it is clear that S_2 has to be odd and since the definition of the series is iterative, it is trivial to show that any S_n is odd, so removing odd numbers like so gives you a ~2x performance boost:

```
def findtreeup(hm, start):
   vv = []
   vv.append(start)
   for x in range(start, hm)[start % 2::2]:
      if hm%x == start:
         start = x
         vv.append(start)
   return vv
```